# Codeignighter issue with groupby

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, activerecord

Im trying to group my data in active record/codeignighter to be able to get a count of how many orders per DAY report.

The `order_date` field is a `INT(11)` that uses `PHP - time()` to populate it with.
There is a `created` field but I havnt used this as yet.

The database looks like this

*(note that the data is just sample and the order_date doesnt match the created date)*

```
id | order_date | order_total |created....
---+------------+-------------+----------
0  | 1411780207 | 12.50       |2014-10-01 00:12:23 ....
1  | 1411750209 | 14.50       |2014-10-02 00:22:33....
1  | 1412780309 | 14.50       |2014-10-02 00:25:33....
```

When I use my code below I get multiple records for the same day becuase I think it is also grouping by the time exact to the second. How would I group only by the date D/M/Y ?

```
public function get_orders($limit = 5, $date_start ='01/01/2001',$date_end='01/12/2001')
{
    //first convert the date format
    $date_start = strtotime( $date_start );
    $date_end = strtotime( $date_end ); 


    $this->db->select('order_date, count(*) as total_orders, sum(order_total) as orders_total');
    $this->db->where('order_date >=', $date_start);
    $this->db->where('order_date <=', $date_end);
    $this->db->order_by('order_date desc', FALSE);
    $this->db->group_by('order_date');
    $this->db->limit($limit);

    return $this->db->get('orders')->result();

}
```

Comment: What is the db field type you used for order_date

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should do like following.

```
$secondOfDay = 86400; //second in a day
$this->db->group_by("CEILING(order_date/{$secondOfDay})");
```

I think that you know what I want to mentioned in the code block above.

Sorry about my English.

Answer (score 0):

You need do group by the day not the datetime. I would change the group by to

```
$this->db->group_by(DATE_FORMAT('order_date', '%y-%m-%d'));
```

This will only return the dates 2014-10-01, 2014-10-02, with 2014-10-02 containing 2 orders.

By grouping by the time as well, you are expecting the orders to have occurred at exactly the same time in a day rather than the same day.